I am staying in France for 4 months. My husband has an EU passport. Am I covered?
I am staying in a house we are renting for 4 months in France. I have a British passport and my husband has an Irish passport. We are staying together in France and plan to come back for another 5 months this year. Am I covered?

Thanks so much for your help. Yes he is with me. He has an Irish passport and yes we are going to apply for a residence card, as we are planning to return to France for 5 months next year also. I find it crazy that we have been everywhere and nobody knows. And more crazy that to apply for one you have to fill out a form that is in French!!!

Covered with? Visa? Health insurance? Something else?

Why is it crazy that government forms in France are in French?

If you’re going to be spending 9/12 months in France, understanding French well enough to be able to complete a government form seems like a given to me. What does “we have been everywhere and nobody knows” refer to?

If you are going to be in France with your husband, and if your husband is not French, then you are a derivative beneficiary of the EU's free movement directive, so you are exempt from the 90/180 rule.  However, you are covered by a requirement to apply for a residence card within three months of your arrival.  The card is free of charge, and it is not clear to me how much the potential fine is for failing to apply for it within three months.
If your husband will be with you but is French, then different rules apply.  If your husband will not be with you, then the normal 90/180 restriction applies.

(+1) On paper, the fine for failing to apply in time is at most €1500 (current level for a “contravention de cinquième classe”), see article R270-2 of the CESEDA. I am not sure it's completely kosher from an EU law perspective (is it proportional and non-discriminatory?) and I have never heard of it being applied but that would be the worst case scenario.

@Relaxed thanks.  I did a quick scan for the level of the fine and found a much higher amount, no doubt because I wasn't reading carefully enough and got an amount for a different class, so I'm glad I didn't include that in the answer.  My mother used to be in this situation every summer, while my father was still alive, and she was of the opinion that applying for a residence card would create an obligation to obtain a French driver's license, even if she was planning to leave after four months, so she never applied and never got in trouble for it ...

@Relaxed ... But in those days there was a different mechanism for penalizing late applications, namely that the application fee was somewhere between €300 and €400 (as opposed to €25 for a timely application).  Since my mother was invariably "found out" at the exit check, there was nothing really to be done.  With the new regulatory structure, it could play out differently, and I have no idea what might actually happen.

" The card is free of charge" - I'm not sure if this is true, as far as I know it could cost as much as a regular ID French citizens must have. In Germany they charge about € 35.

@André but I am sure.  You are right that it does cost as much as a regular French citizen's ID card, but that is also free of charge (see https://passeport.ants.gouv.fr/aide-et-contact/carte-nationale-d-identite -- for the carte de séjour en tant que membre de famille d'un Européen see https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F19315).

@André ah, but that's not the cost of the card. It's the associated handling fees... that's how government agencies sneakily increase the cost of the lot of their products and services.
